# CodeIgniter - result_array in memory

Tags: php, codeigniter

I don't know if this is a valid programming question. But there is something troubling my mind about CodeIgniter. Hope you guys with years of experience and wisdom can guide me.

Here is my story,

I am using CodeIgniter and MS SQL for a project. I am retrieving sales data that is 20M+ rows. Now, I managed to reduce the result by creating aggregated data and store in in the table. Still I get the out of memory error.

Now, I am thinking, does CodeIgniter's result_array() function store all the result to the memory? Am I right with this assumption?

If yes, can I load it instead in chunks? let's say I load top 100 rows in memory, and then delete that 100 rows, and then load another 100 rows? So PHP would not fill my memory with results.

By the way, I already use pager for the detailed data. This question is needed for a specific purpose. I want to show a summary report. I am using [jQwidgets Pivot Grid](https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxpivotgrid/)

I don't know if that makes sense. But that is what I am thinking. I want to understand what is happening. Or maybe you can suggest what other options or design I can make to handle large data in PHP.

Hope I explained myself clearly. Thankyou very much. I would appreciate all your suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the little-known `unbuffered_row` function:

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");

while ($row = $query->unbuffered_row())
{
        echo $row->title;
        echo $row->name;
        echo $row->body;
}
```

> This method returns a single result row without prefetching the whole
>   result in memory as row() does. If your query has more than one row,
>   it returns the current row and moves the internal data pointer ahead.

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html

You can also get an array:

```
$query->unbuffered_row('array');        // associative array
```

Comment: Hi @Alex, thanks for the response. I will take a look and try to make it work in my project. I'll make update once I have findings. Thank you!